# Inchoo facebook connect "Sorry, could not retrieve your Facebook first name. Please try again."

Tags: login, facebook

Hi i am using facebook connect from inchoo.. but when ever i try to login through my account it says "Sorry, could not retrieve your Facebook first name. Please try again."

Comment: Have you tried contacting Inchoo?

Comment: there is no proper instructions on this error.. many people facing same problem.. there are some things on their forum that says this problem can be solved but their is no exact solution. thank you for comment @paj

Comment: Please Download the zip package extract, paste the root directory in your magento website and add your social credentials.

http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/

Comment: i used that package only but no solution. facebook login is not working after every change.

Comment: Here is the solution: 1) Open `app/code/community/Inchoo/SocialConnect/Model/Facebook/Info.php`                       2) Add `params['fields']` like below: `protected function _load()
{
$this->params[‘fields’] = ‘first_name,last_name,email'; /* need to add this line only */
try{
$response = $this->client->api(` via http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/comment-page-5/#comment-430724

Comment: is not working in new version. I’m using 0.3.5 version.This is what I did:edit your file : app\code\community\Inchoo\SocialConnect\Model\Facebook\Info.php, line 97, change `$this->params` to 
`array (
     'fields' =>     'id,name,first_name,last_name,link,birthday,gender,email,picture.type(large)'
 )`
It will be like this :
`$response = $this->client->api(
                '/me',
                'GET',
                array(
                        'fields' =>                        'id,name,first_name,last_name,link,birthday,gender,email,picture.type(large)'
                  )
          );`

Comment: you can read my comment in here : http://inchoo.net/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/comment-page-5/#comment-430812 or here : https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_SocialConnect/issues/40?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Comment: Open /app/code/community/Inchoo/SocialConnect/controllers/FacebookController.php

CHANGE 
$userInfo = $client->api('/me');
TO
$userInfo = $client->api('/me','GET', array('fields' => 'id,name,first_name,last_name,link,birthday,gender,email,picture.type(large)'
    ));